# How to select all the checkbox in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

When I try to select all the items in filter, it is selected only when I scroll it manually if not only few options which is visible without scrolling is getting selected, How to select all the options in swiggy filter in cuisine?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code loops over the list of filters and scrolls down when necessary using javascript.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

...do something and then open the Filters sidebar...

# loop over the filters and scroll if necessary
for box in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=checkbox] + span'):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', box)
    box.click()
```